# How do I drop leftmost digits from a float?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I was trying to print out sub-seconds timing in a bash shell, using Python.

This is somewhat related to [how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively).  I'm on macos and bash provides no subsecond timings there.

If I use `python -c 'from time import time; print(f"{time():.3f}")'` for example I get:

```
1603052253.465
```

`python -c 'from time import time; print(f"{time():4.3f}")'` has the same output behavior.

Now, this quite noisy.  I don't really need to see all the leftmost digits to eyeball execution time from step to step.

I wrote a new script that does it much more nicely:

```
$ time4bash.py

 2325.987

$ time4bash.py

 2328.201
```

But the code to do it was somewhat more involved than I would have preferred.

```
from time import time
time_ = time()
stime = f"{time_:.3f}"

#look for decimal separator, and this will break on `,` locales
pos = stime.index(".")
tstime = stime[pos-4:]

print(tstime)
```

Is there a better way using either string format flags or modulo math?

Comment: You can also do something like this `time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute the remainder modulo 10,000 before formatting it with `.3f`:

```
>>> t = time.time()
>>> t
1603052957.262341

>>> t % 10000
2957.2623410224915

>>> '{:.3f}'.format(t % 10000)
'2957.262'
```

or put all together in one line:

```
print('{:.3f}'.format(time.time() % 10000))
```

Comment: argggh.  I even mentioned modulo math, but I had a mental block about it for some reason and was thinking in terms of that really long 10-something digits i.e. time % 10000000 or something.  And also thought modulo only worked on integers.  Should have just tried it.  Accepted, as soon as timer is up.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert time to hour, min, secs only, you can try something like this.

```
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
```

This will return:

```
'20:42:13'
```

You can also get local time using:

```
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
```

This will return:

```
'13:47:54'
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking for numerical value only. @ShadowRanger solution works perfectly as you can do mod 10000. My answer was to give you an alternate option than doing division.

Comment: this will not get me subsecond accuracy and my question was more oriented towards float formatting in general, even though it was asked in a time context.  also, if you look at the linked question, it uses bash `bc` to do time interval calculation, but all it was missing in my case was second fractions.  I can do that, I think, from my/ShadowRanger's output, not from yours.  I didn't downvote, but it wasn't what I was asking for.

Comment: all good; should have focused more on the question than providing alternate options. time.time()%10000 does the trick